# Evaluate $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty}\sum_{k=n+1}^{2n}\frac{|\sin 1|+2|\sin 2|+\cdots+k|\sin k|}{k^3}$.

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series, limits

Evaluate

> $$\lim\limits_{n \to \infty}\sum_{k=n+1}^{2n}\frac{|\sin  1|+2|\sin
>  2|+\cdots+k|\sin k|}{k^3}.$$

At least, we can estimate an upper bound as follows:

\begin{align*}
\sum_{k=n+1}^{2n}\frac{|\sin
1|+2|\sin 2|+\cdots+k|\sin k|}{k^3}&\le\sum_{k=n+1}^{2n}\frac{1+2+\cdots+k}{k^3}\\&=\sum_{k=n+1}^{2n}\frac{k+1}{2k^2}\\&=\frac{1}{2}\sum_{k=n+1}^{2n}\frac{1}{k}+\frac{1}{2}\sum_{k=n+1}^{2n}\frac{1}{k^2}\\&\to \frac{1}{2}\ln 2(n \to \infty).
\end{align*}
But how to obtain the lower bound?

Comment: How did you get the last step for ln2?

Comment: @Bhaswat the second series vanishes because it is bounded above by $n/(n+1)^2$. For the first series, use the asymptotic $\sum_{k=1}^{N} 1/k = \log(N) + \gamma + O(1/N)$; then the first series can be written as $\log(2n) +\gamma -\log(n)-\gamma +O(1/n)\to \log(2)$.

Comment: Thank you. This helps. Are we looking for a very strict Lower bound here so that the series converges to the same limit? Can we take out x = min{|sink|} and then find a lower bound as 0.5*x*ln2?

Comment: @Bhaswat Nope. $| \sin k |$ can be arbitrarily close to $0$.

Comment: Did a bit of computation. Looks like $\sum(i|sin(i)|) /\sum(i)$ when sum is taken over i from 1 to k converges to a number close to .63662. So by same computations, limit seems to be 0.5*0.693*.63662 =0.22. First thought that .63662 is just approximating to 1-1/e, but seems like it is not the case. But really interesting to see the fraction of sum converge. May be there is an analytical way of computing that limit and we can use that to calculate exact limit of the given sequence.

Comment: The limit seems to be $\frac{\ln 2}{\pi} \approx 0.2206356$. I use Maple.

Comment: Here’s my rough intuition for why I would expect $\frac{\ln 2}{\pi}$: the average value of $|\sin x|$ for $0<x<\pi$ is $\frac {2} {\pi}$. Since the integers mod $\pi$ are uniformly distributed, this means that the average value of $\sin k$ for an integer $k$ is the same $\frac {2} {\pi}$. If we multiply that by the original result for the upper bound, we get $\frac{\ln 2}{\pi}$

Comment: Came here to say exactly the same @Robo300! So I believe that will be the limit we are looking for here. Even though proving the intermediate steps seems a bit challenging.

Comment: With the help of Maple, the limit is $\frac{\ln 2}{\pi}$. However, we need step-by-step solution.

Answer (score 6):

$$\left|\sin x\right| = \frac{2}{\pi}-\sum_{m\geq 1}\frac{4}{\pi(4m^2-1)}\cos(2m x) =\frac{2}{\pi}-f(x)$$
where $f(x)$ is a Lipschitz-continuous, $\pi$-periodic, even function with mean zero. It follows that

$$ \sum_{k=n+1}^{2n}\frac{1}{k^3}\sum_{j=1}^{k}j\left|\sin j\right|=\frac{2}{\pi}\sum_{k=n+1}^{2n}\frac{k+1}{2k^2}-\sum_{k=n+1}^{2n}\frac{1}{k^3}\sum_{j=1}^{k}j\cdot f(j) $$
and by letting $F(m)=f(1)+f(2)+\ldots+f(m)$ and invoking summation by parts we have
$$ \sum_{k=n+1}^{2n}\frac{1}{k^3}\sum_{j=1}^{k}j\left|\sin j\right|=\frac{\log 2}{\pi}+o(1)-\sum_{k=n+1}^{2n}\frac{1}{k^3}\left(k F(k)-\sum_{j=1}^{k-1}F(j)\right) $$
and the claim
$$ \lim_{n\to +\infty}\sum_{k=n+1}^{2n}\frac{1}{k^3}\sum_{j=1}^{k}j\left|\sin j\right|=\frac{\log 2}{\pi} $$
simply follows from the boundedness of $F(x)$, granted by [Weyl's criterion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equidistribution_theorem).
Actually we just need $F(x)=o(x)$, which is fairly obvious given the premises.