# About $\sum_{m=1}^k m |\sin m| = \int_0^k x |\sin x| \mathrm{d} x + O(k)$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits

> *Problem*: Is there an alternative way to get $\sum_{m=1}^k m |\sin m| = \int_0^k x |\sin x| \mathrm{d} x + O(k)$?

*Motivation*: Sometimes we apply Euler-Maclaurin summation formula to estimate the summations. Can we apply something like Euler-Maclaurin summation formula here?

*Remark 1*: I prefer to see something like Euler-Maclaurin summation method (or other nice approaches),
rather than something using $|\sin x| = \frac{2}{\pi} - \sum_{m\ge 1} \frac{4}{\pi (4m^2-1)} \cos (2m x)$
or the equidistribution theorem, if possible.
See: [Evaluate $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty}\sum_{k=n+1}^{2n}\frac{|\sin 1|+2|\sin 2|+\cdots+k|\sin k|}{k^3}$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3736567/evaluate-lim-limits-n-to-infty-sum-k-n12n-frac-sin-12-sin-2-c/3736746#3736746)

*Remark 2*: It is quite easy to get $\int_0^k x |\sin x| \mathrm{d} x = \frac{k^2}{\pi} + O(k)$ by
using $\int_{N\pi}^{(N+1)\pi} x|\sin x| \mathrm{d} x = |\int_{N\pi}^{(N+1)\pi} x\sin x \mathrm{d} x| = (2N+1)\pi$ for $N \in \mathbb{N}_{>0}$.
On the other hand, one may prove $\sum_{m=1}^k m |\sin m| = \frac{k^2}{\pi} + O(k)$ directly, not via $\sum_{m=1}^k m |\sin m| = \int_0^k x |\sin x| \mathrm{d} x + O(k)$ (as a result, $\sum_{m=1}^k m |\sin m| = \int_0^k x |\sin x| \mathrm{d} x + O(k)$ is proved). However, I prefer to see a proof of $\sum_{m=1}^k m |\sin m| = \frac{k^2}{\pi} + O(k)$
via $\sum_{m=1}^k m |\sin m| = \int_0^k x |\sin x| \mathrm{d} x + O(k)$, if possible.

Euler-Maclaurin summation method requires the function being differentiable. However, $x\mapsto x|\sin x|$ is not differentiable at some points.
To overcome this, I introduce
$|\sin m| = \lim_{a\to \infty} \frac{2}{\pi} \sin m \arctan (a \sin m)$ for $m \in \mathbb{N}_{> 0}$
to get $\sum_{m=1}^k m |\sin m| = \lim_{a\to \infty} \sum_{m=1}^k \frac{2}{\pi} m\sin m \arctan (a \sin m)$.
Then by Fact 1 given later, I try to prove the following but have not yet succeeded:

> Let $a > 0$. Let $f(x) = \frac{2}{\pi} x \sin x \arctan (a \sin x)$.
> Prove that there exists an absolute constant $C$ such that
> $|\int_0^k (x - \lfloor x \rfloor - \tfrac{1}{2})f'(x) \mathrm{d} x | < Ck$.

*Fact 1*: Let $f$ is continuously differentiable on $(0, \infty)$. Then
$$\sum_{m=1}^k f(m) = \int_0^k f(x) \mathrm{d} x + \int_0^k (x - \lfloor x \rfloor - \tfrac{1}{2})f'(x) \mathrm{d} x + \frac{1}{2}(f(b)-f(a)).$$
See: [https://www.math.ucdavis.edu/~tracy/courses/math205A/EulerMaclaurinSummation.pdf](https://www.math.ucdavis.edu/%7Etracy/courses/math205A/EulerMaclaurinSummation.pdf)

Any comments and solutions are welcome.

Comment: There is no need to introduce this arctan smoothing if you don't really want to. Reading the proof of the Eurler Maclaurin Summation formula, nowhere is it used that $f'$ is continuous. The only property used is that $f = \int f'$, i.e. that $f$ is absolutely continuous. Of course any $f$ whose derivative has at most countably many discontinuities is absolutely continuous, so the summation formula can be used.

Comment: @nullUser Thank you for your valuable comment.